# Replace function in CF9

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I need to use the replace function on my subject line when sending an email to replace some html code.

My issue is when the subject line contains code like "®"

This is my code, any help is appreciated

> SUBJECT="Regarding Your #mailStruct.procedure# Inquiry"

Comment: It would be helpful to see one of these "bad" subject lines and what the desired outcome would be.

Comment: You state you have an "issue", but you never state what your "issue" actually is.  What *happens* when your subject line contains &reg;?  And how does that vary from your expectation?  Improve your "question" and I'll remove the down-vote from it, and maybe we can answer it (I have no idea how it is people are providing the answers they have, based on the info you're giving them?)...

Comment: I was in a rush when I was writing the question. I apologize for that. My issue was that the &reg; code could not be translated to the actual "®" because of the & sign. What I needed was to remove the &reg; code from my email subject line when it appeared.

Comment: @AlEverett Botox&reg; Forum (this was the "bad" subject line that I was experiencing) and Botox Forum (was the desired outcome). I did manage to use the replace command and solve  my issue. Thanks for taking the time to read my bad question in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()`, or `replaceNoCase()` for a case insensitive replace. See [cfdocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e0e.html)

```
<cfset subject = replaceNoCase(subject, "text to replace", "new text", "all" ) />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could strip all non alpha characters using regex like so:

```
<cfset subject = reReplaceNoCase( subject, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-\_]+", "", "all" )>
```

Comment: If you want to simply strip quotes, you dont need the weight of the regex engine, simply use `subject = replace( subject, '"', 'all' )`

Comment: the first one gives me an error. "Invalid token c found on line 331 at column 95."

Comment: Fixed it. This is what i did:

> `<cfset subProcedure = replace(mailStruct.procedure ,"&reg;","","ALL") />`

>`<cfoutput>#subProcedure#</cfoutput>`

Comment: The regex version is more powerful as it can strip all characters that do not match your white list but as a result is quite a bit slower.